# Successive multiple file selections by user

Tags: jquery

I am writing an email despatch form in which users should be able to attach files. I would like the user to be able to make more than one successive selection of files (ie select multiple files but not necessarily all at once) and for the whole set to be available to the server in the $_FILES collection.

What this seems to come down to is, how do I transfer user selections from a field such as

```
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

into another location in the form -- presumably using Jquery -- and then the input cleared so it can be re-used for another user file input?

Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: What you meant by another location in the form?

Comment: Any storage location such as another input. Anywhere that will be submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the path check my code

Here I am inserting the input file path to an image source also to an input hidden array

```js
$("#userfile").change(function(e){

var allimages = e.target.files;

var result = Object.keys(allimages).map(function(key) {
  return [allimages[key]];
});

result.forEach(function(element){

    var image = URL.createObjectURL(element[0]);
    var oImg = document.createElement("img");

    oImg.setAttribute('src', image);
    oImg.setAttribute('width', "100px");

    $('.images').append(oImg);
    
    var files = $("#files").val();
    
    if(!files) {
      image = JSON.stringify(image);     
    } else {
     files = JSON.parse(files);
     var fileval = files instanceof Array ? files : [files];
     
      fileval.push(image);
      image = JSON.stringify(fileval);
    }
    
     $("#files").val(image);
   });
     
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="hidden" id="files" type="files[]" value="" />
<div class="images"></div>
```